# Why is artisan make:controller not making controllers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

```
$ artisan make:controller fooController
Controller created successfully.
```

A controller is not created under app\Http\Controllers and `git status` does not show any changes. Running the command a second time returns "Controller already exists!" `artisan make:model Foo` works fine as does creating a controller by hand, but that's not really fun. What am I missing?

```
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
```

The workstation is Windows and there do not *seem* to be any permission problems.

Edit: Tried running `composer update`, same result.

Comment: not an answer but a suggesion: name your classes with capital letters as first letter (will not fix your issue though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your controller name using capital on the first letter:

```
artisan make:controller FooController
```

Also, according to Laravel naming convention, you don't have to add Controller at the end of the controller name. Use this instead:

```
artisan make:controller Foo
```

make sure your controller name is in singular form

For Example:

```
php artisan make:model Supplier --migration --controller
```

will produce:

-Controller named: SupplierController.php

-Model named: Supplier.php

-Migrations named: 2017_06_17_161642_create_suppliers_table.php (laravel automatically change it into plural form)

Also, try checking your laravel version using: `php artisan --version`
and make sure its 5.4.xx

if not, update your laravel using `composer update`

Comment: `artisan make:controller Foo` exhibits the same behavior. `artisan make:model` appears to not have the "--controller" option in 5.4.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't have --controller option? What happen if you use --controller? does it throw an error? I'm using the newest laravel 5.4 and the --controller option is available for me..

Comment: "[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException] The "--controller" option does not exist." It's also not present under `artisan help make:model`

Comment: @CurtisWeeks have you check your laravel version using php artisan --version?

Comment: Also, try checking the available option for your make:model using= php artisan help make:model

Comment: I think you just hit on the problem. `$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.4.30` vs `$ artisan --version
Laravel Framework version 5.2.39`